# how to use useState on a specific onPress Touchable Opacity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a screen that outputs all the groups a user isnt a member of. Each group has a join button that when clicked adds the user to the members subcollection under groups collection in firestore.
The state of the button is supposed to change from join to Joined when a user clicks the join button and then change from joined to join when the user clicks it again.

My problem is that since all the buttons have the same joinedButton state which I am listening to, changes of when a user clicks one button the state of all the buttons changes, while only the clicked one should change.
The buttons are outputted using an array map of the promise received from a firestore query.
Any ideas how I can change the state of only the button that has been clicked?

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'

import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { db } from '../../firebase'
import { AuthContext } from '../../navigation/AuthProvider'

const DiscoverGroupList = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [joinedButton, setJoinedButton] = useState(false);
const fetchGroups = async () =>{
//code to
}

    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const joinGroup = async (groupId) => {
        try {
            await db.collection('groups')
                .doc(groupId)
                .collection('members')
                .doc(user.uid)
                .set({
                    userId: user.uid,
                    isMember: true,
                })
            setJoinedButton(true)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    const leaveGroup = async (groupId) => {
        try {
            await db.collection('groups')
                .doc(groupId)
                .collection('members')
                .doc(user.uid)
                .delete()
            setJoinedButton(false)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchGroups()
    
    }, [joinedButton])

    return (
<>
{groupsYouManage.map((item) => (


                        <View key={item.groupId} style={styles.groupWrapper}>

                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                <Image source={{ uri: item.groupImage }} style={styles.groupImage} />

                                <View>
                                    <Text style={styles.groupListTitle}>{item.groupName}</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.groupMembers}>{item.groupMembers}</Text>
                                </View>

                            </View>
                            {!joinedButton ? (
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.join} onPress={() => joinGroup(item.groupId)}>
                                    <Text style={styles.joinText}>Join</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                            ) : (
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.join} onPress={() => leaveGroup(item.groupId)}>
                                    <Text style={styles.joinText}>Joined</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            )
                            }
                        </View>



                    ))}
</>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting a value in the database of members collection with the ID and isMember: true. Is it possible that when you map over the data instead of rendering the button based off of the useState joinedButton, could you set the button to be rendered based on the isMember bool?

```
{item.isMember ? <leaveGroup button /> : <joinGroupButton />}
```

Comment: Maybe this might be my best option. The problem is that the members collection is only for users that are members of the group. The current screen loads groups that the user is not a member of. So all of them will have a Join by default and if they are a member of the group thec group wont be loaded by defualt. .

Answer (score 0):

I think creating separate state for every item present in the array can help.

```
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
    
    import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
    import { db } from '../../firebase'
    import { AuthContext } from '../../navigation/AuthProvider'
    
    const DiscoverGroupList = ({ navigation }) => {
        
    const fetchGroups = async () =>{
    //code to
    }
    
        const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
        const joinGroup = async (groupId) => {
            try {
                await db.collection('groups')
                    .doc(groupId)
                    .collection('members')
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .set({
                        userId: user.uid,
                        isMember: true,
                    })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        const leaveGroup = async (groupId) => {
            try {
                await db.collection('groups')
                    .doc(groupId)
                    .collection('members')
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .delete()
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    
        useEffect(() => {
            fetchGroups()
        
        }, [joinedButton])
    
        return (
    <>
    {groupsYouManage.map((item) => {
    const [joinedButton, setJoinedButton] = useState(false);

    const handleJoin = () => {
      joinGroup(item.groupId)
      setJoinedButton(true);
    }
    const handleLeave = () => {
      leaveGroup(item.groupId)
      setJoinedButton(false);
    }
    
    return (
      <View key={item.groupId} style={styles.groupWrapper}>

          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <Image source={{ uri: item.groupImage }} style={styles.groupImage} />

              <View>
                  <Text style={styles.groupListTitle}>{item.groupName}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.groupMembers}>{item.groupMembers}</Text>
              </View>

          </View>
          {!joinedButton ? (
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.join} onPress={handleJoin }>
                  <Text style={styles.joinText}>Join</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

          ) : (
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.join} onPress={handleLeave}>
                  <Text style={styles.joinText}>Joined</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          )
          }
      </View>



  )})}
    </>
    )
```

Comment: I cant call useState hooks in a loop I get an error. **Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by GroupsYouManage. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of 
Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks**

Comment: try putting all the things that you rendering over loop in a separate component and pass props for your state and a callback function to update the state